# Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting an error and honestly don't understand why it's showing up.
This happens when sending data to the server.
Here is the error text:

> 302 this is response.statusCode
>
> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
> E/flutter ( 5424):  E/flutter ( 5424): ^ E/flutter (
> 5424): E/flutter ( 5424): #0 _ChunkedJsonParser.fail
> (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5) E/flutter ( 5424): #1
> _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9) E/flutter ( 5424): #2
> _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22) E/flutter (5424): #3
> _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10) E/flutter (5424): #4 JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
> E/flutter (5424): #5 JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
> E/flutter ( 5424): #6 LoginCubit.auth
> (package:muraba/features/presentation/login/cubit/login_cubit.dart:29:16)
> E/flutter ( 5424):  E/flutter ( 5424): #7
> LoginBody.build.
> (package:muraba/features/presentation/login/login.dart:144:21)
> E/flutter ( 5424):  E/flutter ( 5424):E/flutter (5424):

Here is my request:

```
Future<void> auth(int number, String device_key)async {
  emit(LoginLoading());

  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ConfigUrl.sendMessage),
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
      "phone": number
      "device_key": device_key
  }));

  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print(responseJson);
    emit(LoginLoaded(loginModel: LoginModel.fromJson(responseJson)));
  } else {
    print(response.statusCode);
    log(json.decode(response.body));
    emit(LoginError());
  }
}
```

Here is a button that sends data to the server:

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 20),
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () async {
      final number = int.parse(_numberEditingController.text);
      const device_key = 'asdarwefvxcgczxcvvd';
      await context.read<LoginCubit>().auth(number, device_key);
      // context.go('/home');
    },
    child: Container(
      width: double.infinity
      color: Colors.green,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
      child: Text('Continue', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
    ),
  ),
)
```

response server - [image: response]

Comment: @Daniil, can you add the JSON response you're getting from the API call? Looks like the JSON response you're receiving isn't valid. Do check the response.

Comment: @OMiShah check please. Or how can i print the long response in the console so that it is not hidden behind "^"?

Comment: @Daniil, add ``print(response.body);`` in your code  just before the line``if(response.statusCode == 200)`` which should print the json response in your debug console / terminal. Do check

Comment: @OMiShah ii get only this - status, html and something hidden behind "^" symbol
You can see this in the first two lines of my error, where I put all the entries from the console

Comment: @OMiShah - `<!DOCTYPE html>
Itte ( 5424): <html>
Itte ( 5424):     <head>
Iter ( 5424):         <meta charset="UTF-8" />
I/utter ( 5424):         <meta http-equiv="refresh" cotent="0;url='http://muraba2.isp.regruhosting.ru'" />
I/flutter ( 5424):         <title>Redirecting to http://muraba2.isp.regruhosting.ru</title>
I/flutter ( 5424):     </head>
I/flutter ( 5424):     <body>
I/flutter ( 5424):         Redirecting to <a href="http://muraba2.isp.regruhosting.ru">http://muraba2.isp.regruhosting.ru</a>.
I/flutter ( 5424):     </body>
I/flutter ( 5424): </html>
I/flutter ( 5424): 302`

Comment: The api is returning HTML content and not a JSON response which is causing the issue. Kindly, check your API endpoint. Also, are you using any framework for backend API ? If you're using Laravel or any other framework kindly, send ``accept: application/json`` header with the request.

Comment: @OMiShah - Check the screenshot, there is an answer from the postman

Comment: @OMiShah The server is really written in Laravel. But, I didn't quite understand what I need to do.

Comment: And yes, the server is written by another person

Comment: I am saying change ``http.post(Uri.parse(ConfigUrl.sendMessage)`` to ``http.post(Uri.parse(ConfigUrl.sendMessage), headers: {"accept": "application/json"}, body: ...``